# How to hide a class on li hover?

Tags: html, css

I have a basic navigation bar,

How can I hide a css class on hover of the li element.

```
<li>
     <span class="span-line"></span>

        <a href="{node_url}" >
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
              Title
        </a>

 </li>
```

Any help would be great :)

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Sorry, I'm not understanding exactly what you need

Comment: Which class do you want to hide?

Comment: The span-line class :)

Comment: li:hover + .span-line {display:none} ??

Comment: The title explains what I'm asking for @ForgetfulFellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS selector:

```
   li:hover .span-line{
        display:none;
   }
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/rsX4D/

Answer (score 2):

You'd use:

```
li:hover > .span-line {
    display:none;
}
```

to achieve this.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uB9h7/1/)**

Comment: what does the > sign mean in css ?

Comment: @AdamKolinski It's the [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors).

Comment: I'm not sure the child selector is necessary since you can only hover over one li at a time.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Maybe, but it doesn't hurt. I prefer to always use the child selector when applicable, it's more efficient.